# Permalink, links a page to the homepage

Tags: permalinks, archives

So I'm using the 'post-name' pretty permalink structure.

I have a page called The Trust, the slug of this page is the-trust.

But when i go onto www.mydomain.com/the-trust, it shows the the homepage. The URL stays the same, but it displays the index.php page.

It used to show me the archive.php page, but I removed that from my theme files so now it shows me the index page.

How can I fix this?

- If i change the slug to the-trusts, it displays the page fine, however I want the slug to stay as the-trust.
- I used to have a php file in my theme folder called thetrust.php (i've removed that now), the template file that is assigned to The Trust page is called trust-articles.php

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The page does work with Ugly permalinks so www.domain.com/?page_id=174

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to Settings/Permalinks and click Save Changes. That will flush the permalinks.
You could look at the '[Debug wp_redirect](http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-wp-redirect/)' plugin.

Edit: Another idea is to determine what template file is in use. I have a small function plugin that adds debug comments to the header and footer for logged in Editors or Admins.

I have uploaded it to pastebin.com. Copy it to a text file and upload it to wp-content/mu-plugins or to wp-content/plugins and then activate it. Reload your page and search for "get_template_name" and tell us the filenames listed on that line and the 2 lines after it.

http://pastebin.com/tuJhcyHP

Comment: Hey, I tried resetting the permalinks but it did not work. Also the plugin didnt seem to display anything on the homepage.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a link to a debug function plugin that I wrote and use a lot. Maybe I should have added another answer but SE seemed to discourage this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. The problem was that I didnt have an archive page for The Trust posts, so it was leading to default archive page, and when I deleted that it redirecred to homepage. So to fix it I just created a custom-archive page. Now it works.